# redirected to instagram-auth-failure#_ in dymantic/instagram

Tags: laravel, instagram, instagram-api, laravel-10, laravel-package

im using dymantic/laravel-instagram-feed package , but when i login to instagram after putting the client_id and redirect_uri, it redirects me to localhost/instagram-auth-failure# , thats the code and website
[image]

[image]

[image]

i know why its 404, because i dont have route for that, but i want to redirect to auth_success